# Creating a shortlist in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a fairly generic question about how to create a shortlist in rails.

What I currently have is a user and job model where users can register and create/edit jobs etc. What I would like to do is enable users to add jobs they are interested in to a "shortlist" so that they can easily come back to them - I would then want to add these shortlisted jobs to my user dashboard.

I was wondering what would be the best way to implement a setup like this? Would it be best to create a seperate controller for shortlists and make this a nested resource of users and then link my jobs table with my shortlist table in my database?

Would be great to get some ideas from anyone who has implemented anything like this before?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, it sounds like you want a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many) relationship here as far as the modeling goes -

User:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :shortlisted_jobs, :class_name => 'Job'
```

Job:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :shortlisting_users, :class_name => 'User'
```

As far as the controller setup, I would put the job CRUD into a `JobsController`, that isn't namespaced, and add the needed actions for manipulating a particular user's shortlist into the `UsersController`.

The one assumption I'm making is that me, as a user in your app, can add a job that you created to my shortlist. If this is the case, I would set it up how I just described.

Comment: This is excellent, thanks so much for reply. Only part I am slightly confused on is adding the CRUD that isn't namespaced? Without having my code here to review I believe I will currently have `class JobsController < ApplicationController` - how would the not namespaced part work with this? Thanks again :)

Comment: having `class JobsController < ApplicationController` means it's not namespaced :) If it were namespaced, it would be something more like `class Users::JobsController < ApplicationController`, the file would be at `app/controllers/users/jobs_controller`, and the `resources :jobs` route declaration would be within the `resources :users` block in your routes. I think you're good to go here.